# Cryptic error: `.A !=< .A₁ of type Set` in simple function

Tags: agda

The following Agda function should lookup a list, looping back on index overflows:

```
module Test where

open import Prelude.Nat
open import Prelude.List

roundIndex : {A : Set} -> Nat -> A -> List A -> A
roundIndex n x xs = go n xs where
  go : {A : Set} -> Nat -> List A -> A
  go (suc n) (x ∷ xs) = go n xs
  go (suc n) []       = go n xs
  go zero    (x ∷ xs) = x
  go zero    []       = x
```

But won't compile with the following cryptic error:

```
/Users/v/vic/dev/agda/Test.agda:10,25-32
.A !=< .A₁ of type Set
when checking that the expression go n xs has type .A₁
```

It seems like Agda isn't properly passing the implicit `A` to `go`, but passing it explicitly didn't solve the problem. What is this error? Also, that is `!=<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that `go` works for any `A`, but you try to return outer `x` and `xs` with outer `A` types. The `go`-bound `A` and `roundIndex`-bound `A` types are different, hence the error. In general, bound type variables are only equal to themselves during conversion checking. It's not Agda-specific, as you could reproduce the same error in Haskell as well.

The solution is to remove the inner type quantification:

```
roundIndex : {A : Set} -> Nat -> A -> List A -> A
roundIndex {A} n x xs = go n xs where
  go : Nat -> List A -> A
  go (suc n) (x ∷ xs) = go n xs
  go (suc n) []       = go n xs
  go zero    (x ∷ xs) = x
  go zero    []       = x
```

Now there's only one shared `A` around.